# Moving postgresql data to different drive

Tags: postgresql, tablespaces, postgresql-9.1

I am using AWS as my cloud environment. I installed PostgreSQL on the same drive as my root instance volume. I have attached and mounted the second drive to my instance. Now I want to move all my PostgreSQL data to the different drive. I am still in development mode so I can delete the old data if it makes transfer easier at this point of time. What is the best way to do this?

Is PostgreSQL tablespace something which I should look at?

Comment: Tablespaces would be the way to go if you wanted to move *part* of your database(s) to a separate drive.

Comment: This answer suggests that `tablespaces` should *NOT* go on an external hard drive: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/62037/41823 Not sure I understand the risk if you're already putting the data on an external?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The following should do it:

1. Shut down PostgreSQL
2. Make sure PostgreSQL does not run any longer
3. Check that PostgreSQL is really stopped
4. Copy the old data directory to the new drive 
   The data directory is usually defined through a commandline parameter  (`-D`) for your service or through the `PGDATA` environment variable.
5. Update your PostgreSQL configuration (service, environment var) to point to the new data directory. In Windows you can use the `sc` utility or `pg_ctl` (from the Postgres binaries)
6. If you copied the data, rename the old data directory to make sure PostgreSQL cannot find it any longer. That way you'll get an error message if you didn't get the configuration right.
7. Start the service
8. If everything is running fine, you can delete the old directory.

Comment: In 4th point, what do you mean by 'This is usually defined through a commandline parameter...'?

Comment: @codecool: there are several different ways how this could be defined. *Usually* it's part of the service definition. But it depends on your operating system, distribution and personal changes.

Comment: This worked but I used the regedit instead of the command line for Windows. Whew. My disk was just about to run out of space but now I have it safely operating elsewhere with enough space.

Comment: Here is nice step-by-step blog post with specific details, up-to-date for typical ubuntu and 9.5 DB version: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-postgresql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 5):

1. Stop postgresql service
2. cp -a source_data_directory destination_data_directory
3. chown -R postgres_user /destination_data_directory
4. export PGDATA=destination_data_directory
5. Changing data directory to destination_data_directory within postgresql.conf
6. pg_ctl start

Comment: I glad you remembered the `chown` command for the new folder.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a description of how to move an existing PostgreSQL database to a new location (folder, partition), on Arch Linux (this procedure should be similar for other Linux distributions).

`pg_dumpall` is a utility for writing out (dumping) all PostgreSQL databases of a cluster into one script file. ... It does this by calling `pg_dump` for each database in the cluster. ...

For example:

```
## To dump all databases:
$ pg_dumpall > /tmp/db.out               ## backup all postgres databases to file
$ pg_dumpall -Fc dbname > /tmp/outfile   ## backup a database

## To reload database(s) from that file:
$ psql -f /tmp/db.out postgres
```

---

**TL/DR**

You need to:

- export (`pg_dumpall`) database
- create new EMPTY directory
- edit postgresql.conf file
- restart postgres server service
- load old data from dump file into new database

**Summary of commands**

I'm leaving my shell prompts (hostname ...) to clarify what shell I am in as I proceed.

```
[victoria@victoria ~]$ postgres --version     ## postgres (PostgreSQL) 11.2
[victoria@victoria claws]$ sudo -u postgres -i
[postgres@victoria ~]$ pg_dumpall > /tmp/db.out
[postgres@victoria ~]$ psql
[postgres]# SHOW data_directory;              ## /var/lib/postgres/data
[postgres]# exit
[victoria@victoria postgres]$ mkdir /mnt/Vancouver/programming/rdb/postgres/postgresdb
## IMPORTANT: dir must be empty:
[victoria@victoria postgres]$ l postgresdb/   ## total 0
[victoria@victoria postgres]$ sudo chown postgres:root /mnt/Vancouver/programming/rdb/postgres/postgresdb/
[victoria@victoria postgres]$ sudo systemctl status postgresql
  ...
  May 02 19:55:21 victoria systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL database server.
[postgres@victoria ~]$ initdb --locale en_US.UTF-8 -E UTF8 -D '/mnt/Vancouver/programming/rdb/postgres/postgresdb/data'
[postgres@victoria ~]$ exit
[victoria@victoria postgres]$ sudo vim /var/lib/postgres/data/postgresql.conf
  ## added line:
  data_directory = '/mnt/Vancouver/programming/rdb/postgres/postgresdb/data'
[victoria@victoria postgres]$ sudo -u postgres -i
[postgres@victoria ~]$ psql
[postgres]# SHOW data_directory;
  ## /var/lib/postgres/data   ## << Old dir; need to restart postgresql service
[postgres]# \q
[victoria@victoria postgres]$ sudo systemctl restart postgresql
[victoria@victoria postgres]$ sudo -u postgres -i
[postgres@victoria ~]$ psql
[postgres]# SHOW data_directory;
  ## /mnt/Vancouver/programming/rdb/postgres/postgresdb/data
[postgres]# \q
[postgres@victoria ~]$ psql -f /tmp/db.out postgres
  SET
  SET
  SET
  CREATE ROLE
  ALTER ROLE
  [ ... SNIP! ... ]
[postgres@victoria ~]$ exit
## Done!  :-D
```

---

**Example**

See my accompanying blog post, [How to Move an Existing PostgreSQL Database on Arch Linux](https://persagen.com/2019/05/03/move_postgres_database.html), for commented code and output.---

---

**References**

- [good tips] **[How To Move a PostgreSQL Data Directory to a New Location on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-postgresql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04)**
- [postgres docs] **[pg_dumpall](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-dumpall.html)**
- [Arch Linux docs] [Manual Dump and Reload](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PostgreSQL#Manual_dump_and_reload)
- [StackOverflow] [Copying PostgreSQL Database to Another Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237725/copying-postgresql-database-to-another-server)
- [StackOverflow] [PostgreSQL Dump Permission Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835835/postgresql-dump-permission-denied)

Answer (score 0):

**@a_horse_with_no_name** answers works great but I needed to modified it bit so systemctl works with it.

```
sudo systemctl edit postgresql-13

# Note: This overrides base systemctl file
[Service]
Environment=
Environment=PGDATA=new_path
```

Note:
I had to explicitly clear Environment before setting it again, as it is an additive setting, similar to other lists like ExecStart (as a whole, not per-variable) and EnvironmentFile;