# The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted

Tags: postgresql, windows, errors

Whenever I install PostgreSQL, it stops working after about 6 months.  This is the second time this happened!  Last time this happened, I uninstalled and then installed version 4.29.  How can I debug the PostgreSQL client or server and get a stack trace?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Splash screen opens and never closes unless I click on it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I can't show more of the top section of the log because the error dialog pops up.  When closing the error, the system tray icon for PostgreSQL crashes and closes everything.

[image]

[image]

After further troubleshooting, I found 8 "PostgreSQL Server" tasks, 1 pg_ctl task, 1 pgAdmin 4 Desktop Runtime in the Task Manager.  Killed them all and restarted this and restarted the service in Admin Tools > Services.  Same behavior.

C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\postgres.exe

Answer (score 1):

Found these.  We'll give it a shot.

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_a_stack_trace_of_a_running_PostgreSQL_backend_on_Linux/BSD

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_a_stack_trace_of_a_running_PostgreSQL_backend_on_Windows

---

Windows debugging.

Open Environment Variables (WINDOWS key + BREAK)
Set environment variable "_NT_SYMBOL_PATH" for 4.2.

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\debug_symbols;SRV*c:\localsymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

- open pgAdmin 4 > look for process in Task Manager and get process id
- open Microsoft Visual Studio (run as administrator) > Debug > Attach to Process > check "Show processes from all users" > sort by process id > Attach
- now go back in pgAdmin

[image]

Got a new popup I've never seen before from Visual Studio!

[image]

Created new virtual environment based on Python 3.8.

[image]

Created a new Visual Studio Project using Python, not C++.  I might need a newer version of Python based on this fix.

https://github.com/microsoft/ptvs/issues/5853

https://bugs.python.org/issue37633

Since this new version does not show in the Base Interpreter, I created a new environment based on the zip file.

[image]

None of that worked.  Then I stumbled upon the registry configuration for pgAdmin.  I read that pgAdmin uses Python version 2.7.  And the PythonPath variable was blank, so I set it to C:\Python\Python27.  So it must be using a value from somewhere else to get the path.  It's looking in sys.path in Python whatever that is.

[image]

Then I set ApplicationPath to C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v4\web, to the folder where pgadmin4.py is located.

Here is the icon I'm clicking on each time.
"C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v4\runtime\pgAdmin4.exe"
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\bin\pgAdmin4.exe"

> ERROR flask.app: Error starting the app server: (<class 'OSError'>,
> OSError(10013, 'An attempt was made to access a socket in a way
> forbidden by its access permissions', None, 10013, None),

There are two pgAdmin folders.  There are traces left over from the other pgAdmin uninstall.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\files.txt
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\collections
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\encodings
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\importlib
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\json
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\site-packages
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\collections\__pycache__
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\collections\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\encodings\__pycache__
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\encodings\__pycache__\aliases.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\encodings\__pycache__\cp1252.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\encodings\__pycache__\latin_1.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\encodings\__pycache__\utf_8.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\encodings\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\importlib\__pycache__
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\importlib\__pycache__\abc.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\importlib\__pycache__\machinery.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\importlib\__pycache__\util.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\importlib\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\json\__pycache__
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\json\__pycache__\decoder.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\json\__pycache__\encoder.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\json\__pycache__\scanner.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\json\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\site-packages\__pycache__
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\site-packages\__pycache__\_virtualenv.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\abc.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\codecs.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\contextlib.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\copyreg.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\datetime.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\enum.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\functools.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\genericpath.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\heapq.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\io.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\keyword.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\ntpath.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\operator.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\os.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\re.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\reprlib.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\signal.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\site.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\sre_compile.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\sre_constants.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\sre_parse.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\stat.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\subprocess.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\threading.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\types.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\warnings.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\_bootlocale.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\_collections_abc.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\_sitebuiltins.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\_weakrefset.cpython-38.pyc
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Lib\__pycache__\__future__.cpython-38.pyc
```

FINALLY SOLVED IT!  Flask within the Qt framework is NOT getting the port!  I put some troubleshooting code into the source code.

> C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v4\web\pgAdmin4.py

```
# Initialize Flask service only once
# If `WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN` is None, i.e: app is initializing for first time
# so set `use_reloader` = False, thus reload won't call.
# Reference:
# https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/220#issuecomment-11176538
with open("myfile.txt", "w") as file1:
    file1.write("Testing")
    file1.write(config.DEFAULT_SERVER)
    file1.write(config.EFFECTIVE_SERVER_PORT)
try:
    app.run(
        host=config.DEFAULT_SERVER,
        port=config.EFFECTIVE_SERVER_PORT,
        use_reloader=(
            (not app.PGADMIN_RUNTIME) and app.debug and
            os.environ.get("WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN") is not None
        ),
        threaded=config.THREADED_MODE
    )

except IOError:
    app.logger.error("Error starting the app server: %s", sys.exc_info())
```

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28926/moving-postgresql-data-to-different-drive/28927#28927

https://radumas.info/blog/tutorial/2016/08/08/Migrating-PostgreSQL-Data-Directory-Windows.html

Comment: Here's the Python version to install.  Once I have the copy unzipped, I can create a new virtual environment based on this.  https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380b2/

Comment: Might be good to backup your databases before doing something foolish.  C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data\base

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619921/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissi/45355519

Comment: For those with a similar issue, go to this answer for what I did to troubleshoot further.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66427222/640205

Comment: good read: https://www.tutorialfor.com/blog-247643.htm

Comment: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48283/is-a-tcp-server-limited-to-65535-clients

Comment: Had to put in a different logging message to show the entire stack trace.  After that, I fixed two things.  I'll be doing a pull request in GitHub for pgAdmin to make the socket fix standard on major version 4.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66427222/640205